# First three items free?

Tags: javascript, html, list

I'm *very* new to coding and learning as I go.

My current conundrum: trying to create a multi-select list where the first three options  selected (think course subjects, for example) would be free, but every additional selection thereon would carry a $200 fee, and the total would be displayed. Example:

1. Math - $0
2. English - $0
3. History - $0
4. Geography - $200
5. Art - $200

...until the end of the list. There's no limitation on how many options the use can select and no tie-in to a specific options; the first three are free regardless of which option is chosen.

I've been playing around with the W3 list code below because it fits the style of the rest of the form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <h2> Select the Desired Activites </h2>
  <!-- Essential JS 2 MultiSelect's dependent material theme -->
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-dropdowns/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!-- Essential JS 2 all script -->
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

  <!-- Essential JS 2 MultiSelect's dependent scripts -->
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/dist/global/ej2-base.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-data/dist/global/ej2-data.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-inputs/dist/global/ej2-inputs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-buttons/dist/global/ej2-buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-lists/dist/global/ej2-lists.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-popups/dist/global/ej2-popups.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-dropdowns/dist/global/ej2-dropdowns.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Add the HTML <input> element  -->
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" id='select' />
  <script>
    var sportsData = ['Math', 'English', 'History', 'Geography', 'Art'];
    // initialize MultiSelect component
    var listObj = new ej.dropdowns.MultiSelect({
      dataSource: sportsData,
      popupHeight: '200px',
      //set width to popup list
      popupWidth: '250px',
      // set placeholder to MultiSelect input element
      placeholder: "Activity"
    });
    listObj.appendTo('#select');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Create a variable `freeCoursesLeft`. Once it reaches 0, you can start charging.

Comment: Take an array and append to it. Once the length is 3 then start charging.

Comment: Add an event handler that fires every time the user adds or removes an item. The event handler counts the number of selected items. If the total is > 3, then subtract 3 from the total. Multiply that number by 200 to get your dollar amount.

Answer (score 3):

You can count how many items are in the `listObj.value` from `tagging` and `removed` events:

```css
#priceList
{
  white-space: pre;
}

#priceList
{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <!-- Essential JS 2 MultiSelect's dependent material theme -->
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-dropdowns/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!-- Essential JS 2 all script -->
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

  <!-- Essential JS 2 MultiSelect's dependent scripts -->
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/dist/global/ej2-base.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-data/dist/global/ej2-data.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-inputs/dist/global/ej2-inputs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-buttons/dist/global/ej2-buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-lists/dist/global/ej2-lists.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-popups/dist/global/ej2-popups.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-dropdowns/dist/global/ej2-dropdowns.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2> Select the Desired Activites </h2>
  <!-- Add the HTML <input> element  -->
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" id='select' />
  <div class="priceListBox">Price per item: <span id="priceList"></span></div>
  <div>Price total: <span id="price">0</span></div>
  <script>
    var sportsData = ['Math', 'English', 'History', 'Geography', 'Art'];
    // initialize MultiSelect component
    var listObj = new ej.dropdowns.MultiSelect({
      dataSource: sportsData,
      popupHeight: '200px',
      //set width to popup list
      popupWidth: '250px',
      // set placeholder to MultiSelect input element
      placeholder: "Activity",
      

      //event listeners
      tagging: getPrice, //item added
      removed: getPrice  //item removed
    });
    listObj.appendTo('#select');

    //event handler
    function getPrice()
    {
      let price = 0;
      if (listObj.value.length > 3)
        price = (listObj.value.length - 3) * 200; 

      //display total price
      document.getElementById("price").textContent = price;
      
      let priceList = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < listObj.value.length; i++)
      {
        priceList.push(listObj.value[i] + " = " + (i > 2 ? 200 : 0));
      }
      //display prices for each item
      document.getElementById("priceList").textContent = priceList.join("\n");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how did you know about "tagging" and "removed"?

Comment: From the API page https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/api/multi-select/#events. Since they don't have "input" event that would be fired each time input field changed (the `change` event only fires when focus changed...dumb), next logical step would be track when tags are added and removed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want, but you could do an event listener on the tagging event, and then do the calculation with the selected tag length.

```js
var sportsData = ['Math', 'English', 'History', 'Geography', 'Art'];
// initialize MultiSelect component
var listObj = new ej.dropdowns.MultiSelect({
    dataSource: sportsData,
    popupHeight: '200px',
    //set width to popup list
    popupWidth: '250px',
    // set placeholder to MultiSelect input element
    placeholder: "Activity"});

// Listen on tagging event and execute the function to calculate.
listObj.tagging = function () {
    var selectedTags = listObj.value;

    if (selectedTags.length > 3) {
        var total = (selectedTags.length - 3) * 200;

        alert('$' + total);
    }
}

listObj.appendTo('#select');
```

I hope this helps you getting on your way.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/demos/#/material/drop-down-list/default.html), you can read the following about the dropdown, and it's listObj:

> change
> Event
> Triggers when an item in a popup is selected or when the model value is changed by user. Use change event to Configure the Cascading DropDownList

They also provide an example. So I added that to your code, by adding an 'change' property to your `listObj`, and then print the cost through `valueChanged()`.

NOTE: you need to select some activities, and then click somewhere else that's not the dropdown to see the price.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <h2> Select the Desired Activites </h2>
  <!-- Essential JS 2 MultiSelect's dependent material theme -->
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-dropdowns/styles/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!-- Essential JS 2 all script -->
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/dist/ej2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

  <!-- Essential JS 2 MultiSelect's dependent scripts -->
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-base/dist/global/ej2-base.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-data/dist/global/ej2-data.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-inputs/dist/global/ej2-inputs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-buttons/dist/global/ej2-buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-lists/dist/global/ej2-lists.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-popups/dist/global/ej2-popups.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/ej2-dropdowns/dist/global/ej2-dropdowns.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Add the HTML <input> element  -->
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" id='select' />
  <script>
    var sportsData = ['Math', 'English', 'History', 'Geography', 'Art'];
    // initialize MultiSelect component
    var listObj = new ej.dropdowns.MultiSelect({
      dataSource: sportsData,
      popupHeight: '200px',
      //set width to popup list
      popupWidth: '250px',
      // set placeholder to MultiSelect input element
      placeholder: "Activity",
      // ADDED
      change: (event) => { valueChanged(event.value) }
    });
    listObj.appendTo('#select');
    
    // ADDED
    function valueChanged(valueArr) {
      let price = 0,
          maxFreeActivities = 3,
          costPerActivity = 200,
          numberOfSelectedActivities = valueArr.length;
      
      if (numberOfSelectedActivities > maxFreeActivities) {
        price = (numberOfSelectedActivities - maxFreeActivities) * costPerActivity;
      }
      
      console.log('price:', price);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```